# Data structure(s) useful for finding values that can be identified with multiple keys of different types

Tags: lookup-tables

As an example, consider the storage of hospital records. If John Smith is feeling sick, the doctor might need to look up his record by name to find his medical history. However, the doctor might also need to lookup all patients who experienced the symptoms John experienced to help the diagnosis. In another case, he may need a list of all patients admitted to the hospital at a certain time. What data structure(s) would be used to store patient records and search for them based on name, symptom, date of admission, and possibly other identifiers?

Comment: I agree... Seems like a textbook case.

Answer (score 2):

I'll throw this out there: this reads like the use-case for a relational database. Perhaps storing the data in a database and accessing it with queries is a good, long-term solution? If you're interested in the theory/algorithms, you can study how databases solve these problems. Things like indexes, query optimization, etc. are quite deep and probably can't be meaningfully covered here.